# I dont understand whats wrong mith my code with multiple classes (I started c++ multiple classes recently)

Tags: c++

I recently started learning and working on multiple classes but i can't understand why my code doesn't work.

I get these errors:

[errors photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0WP2.png)

This is my code separated in these classes

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "dalykai.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string input;
    dalykai dalykaiObj;

    cout << "Type some name: "; cin >> input;
    dalykaiObj.setName(input);
    cout << "Jusu ivestas vardas yra: " << dalykaiObj.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

dalykai.h

```
#ifndef DALYKAI_H
#define DALYKAI_H

using namespace std;

class dalykai{
    public:
        dalykai();
        void setName(string x);
        string getName();
    protected:
    private:
        string name;
};

#endif // DALYKAI_H
```

dalykai.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "dalykai.h"

using namespace std;

string name;

dalykai::dalykai(){
    cout << "Object was created successfully!\n";
}

dalykai::void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}

dalykai::string getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Comment: `dalykai::void` -- what?

Comment: Stick the class name scope in front of the class member, not in front of the return type. For exampke: `void dalykai::setName(string x) { ... }`

Comment: What is your expected result?  Also, copy and paste complete error message to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
dalykai::void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}
```

It should be:

```
void dalykai::setName(string x){
    name = x;
}
```

In addition. Avoid using `using namespace std` in headers. Your get function should end with const since it doesn't change class member variables.

Comment: i did it as well as i removed using namespace std from header. But how should i write const in get fuction? I understand why to do it but can you tell me how? :)

Comment: @Haruki `void setName(string x) const` :)